# MongoDB Regex with multiple options

Tags: regex, mongodb

How do I search in mongo with regex that has multiple options?

as per [mongo documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) I can do,

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $regex: 'acme.*corp', $options: 'i' } } )
```

How do I do this with multiple options, say, `i` and `m`?

like `$options: 'im'`?

or maybe `$options: ['i', 'm']`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct syntax is this (most probably based on my observation which are listed below):

```
$options: 'im'
```

List of [regex options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with descriptions

**Data**:

```
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello Sam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello sam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello\nSam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello\nsam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello pam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello Pam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello\nPam" })
db.a.insert({"a" : "hello\npam" })
```

**Code**:

```
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : 'is'}})       // Sam, sam, \nSam, \nsam
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : 'i'}})        // Sam, sam, 
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : 's'}})        // sam, \nsam
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : ['i']}})      // sam
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : ['i', 's']}}) // sam
 db.a.find({a : {$regex : 'o.+sam', $options : ['s']}})      // sam
```